# How can I use LDAP-Record Authentication in my Laravel APP without providing a default username and password?

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, active-directory, ldap

I'm using the LdapRecord PHP Package for my Laravel REST Application. I'm also using JWTAuth for authenticate the user via a json web token.

I want to authenticate a user using his username and password from Active Directory using the LDAP protocol.

I have already configured my `auth.php` and my user model for Database Authentication via LDAP Record:

`auth.php:`

```
    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'ldap',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],

    'guards' => [
        // jwt with ldap auth
        'ldap' => [
            'driver' => 'jwt',
            'provider' => 'ldap',
        ],
    ],


    'providers' => [
        'ldap' => [
            'driver' => 'ldap',
            'model' => LdapRecord\Models\ActiveDirectory\User::class,
            'rules' => [],
            'scopes' => [],
            'database' => [
                'model' => App\Models\User::class,
                'sync_passwords' => false,
                'password_column' => false,
                'sync_attributes' => [
                    'email' => 'mail',
                    'username' => 'samaccountname',
                    'fname' => 'givenName',
                    'lname' => 'sn'
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
```

`User.php:`

```
class User extends Authenticatable implements LdapAuthenticatable, JWTSubject
{
    use AuthenticatesWithLdap;

    protected $table = 'users';
    protected $primaryKey = 'guid';
    public $incrementing = false;
    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $fillable = [

    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'guid'
    ];

    protected $casts = [
        
    ];

    /**
     * JWT - Functions
     */
    public function getJWTIdentifier()
    {
        return $this->getKey();
    }
    public function getJWTCustomClaims()
    {
        return [];
    }
}
```

**My Problem now:**
In the .env file or the ldap config file you can provide a default username and password. I do not want to do this. So i read the docs and found that i need to set both values to "null".

When i do this my login fails with the message invalid username and password. **But** if I provide a default username and password, the login works as it should and i get my authenticatet user back.

Here is my Login function:

```
 public function login(Request $request) {
        // Check if username and password are passed
        $credentials = $request->only(['username', 'password']);
        if(!array_key_exists('username', $credentials) || !array_key_exists('password', $credentials) ) {
            return json_response(400, false, __('_.ERR_MISSING_CREDENTIALS'));
        }
        // Map username to samaccountname
        $credentials['samaccountname'] = $credentials['username'];
        unset($credentials['username']);
        // Check if auth is successful
        if(!$token = Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
            return json_response(401, false, __('_.ERR_WRONG_CREDENTIALS'));
        }
        return json_response(200, true, __('_.MSG_LOGGED_IN'))
           ->withCookie(cookie(config('_re.session_cookie_name'), $token, config('jwt.ttl')));
    }
```

How can i log in with the build in Auth guard with the configured guards and providers, without provide a default username and password for the ldap record package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some trial and error and asking on github, I found a workaround to use database authentication without a standard username and password.

**The solution:**

I take the connection from the container and edit the default configuration at runtime with `$connection->setConfiguration($config)`. I use the entered user data as the standard user name and password.
The current connection is established with the login data entered and no standard user has to be specified in the configuration.
I'll list the code below.

```
[...]
$credentials = $request->only(['username', 'password']);
 if(!array_key_exists('username', $credentials) || !array_key_exists('password', $credentials) ) {
     return json_response(400, false, __('_.ERR_MISSING_CREDENTIALS'));
}

// Map username to samaccountname
$credentials['samaccountname'] = $credentials['username'];
unset($credentials['username']);

/*
The solution:
I change the default username and passwort in the connection configuration and try to search with these credentials.
If this account could not be found, the auth attempt will return false.
*/
$default_conf = config('ldap.connections.default');
$default_conf['username'] = $credentials['samaccountname'];
$default_conf['password'] = $credentials['password'];

$connection = Container::getDefaultConnection();
$connection->setConfiguration($default_conf);

// Check if auth is successful
if(Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
    return json_response(401, false, 'Wrong credentials'));
}
[...]
```